# Is it safe to access Base protected member this way?

Tags: c++, xcode, protected

I have two classes:

```
class base
{
protected:
   int x;
};

class der: public base
{
   void Acc(base& b)
   {
      b.*(&der::x) = 5;
   }
};
```

Is it safe to access a base protected member this way (&der::x) ?
I'm worried that it could point to a wrong variable.

---

This is the way to pass by accessing protected member of a base class object.

[image]

The above code:

[image]

Comment: you just inherited it why would you need to access it like that

Comment: also this doesn't even compile

Comment: I guess you are into code that is easy to maintain. Or do you have a problem with job security?

Comment: TC++PL states that "A derived class can access a base class’ protected members only for objects of its own type. This prevents subtle errors that would otherwise occur when one derived class corrupts data belonging to other derived classes."

Comment: Actually, I use XCode, and the above code is compiled !
However, thank all you guys any ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might find difficult to understand the below line

```
b.*(&der::x) = 5;
```

It can be written as:

```
b.*(&(der::x)) = 5;
```

As scope resolution operator can be omitted as we have only one variable named `x` in base and derived class.

```
b.*(&x) = 5;
```

Which is nothing but taking address of `x` and then again dereferencing it. It can be written as:

```
b.x = 5;
```

Which I hope you might be aware of. But your code won't compile if you use `b.x` instead of 'b.*(&der::x) = 5;' as 'x' is protected and this is used to bypass the compiler rule which prevents us from writing `b.x = 5;`

Comment: It wouldn't compile without the *complicated statement*.

Comment: @dalle It is compiling and running fine for me. can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: @dalle I'm using VS2010 and it is running fine on it.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 and I'm getting a error C2248: 'base::x' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'base'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's *safe* - but it is more than a little weird, and will be confusing to readers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't make thing too complicated. When you compile this code it will never
compile. I will tell you why this code is complicated and why it will not compile.

```
1> Why this code is complicated ?
According to the basic of c++ we can easily access the protected member of base 
class in drive class. So you can write you code like this.
```

> class base {
>             protected:
>                   int x;
>       } // End of base class
>
> class der: public base {
>              void Acc() {
>                   x = 5;
>              }
>       }// End of der class.

```
 2> Why this code will not compile ?
```

> *(&der::x) = 5;

This statement is correct and compile because it will put the value in x variable
   which is part of der class after the inheritance. In other word we can say that 
   statement.

> x = 5;
>
> *(&der::x) = 5;

are equivalent and doing same thing, but if you write a statement like

> b.(*(&der::x)) = 5;

It will generate error because when you use dot operator(.) to call the member of
   class then just after the (.) you have to specify the member of the class.
   So in above expression only x is the member of the class b except all will 
   generate error.

```
Conclusion, if code will not compile then how we can say it is safe or not. Code is
safe or not is depend on the resource utilization, which it will during runtime.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is an implicit cast, it is the same thing as writing `static_cast<der&>(b).x = 5;`

It is safe as long as you can be sure that the `b` argument is always of type `der`. What happens if you call it with some other type derived from `base`? That type could use `x` for something else than `der`.

```
class nuclear_submarine: public base {};

void dostuff(der d)
{
   nuclear_submarine ns;
   d.Acc(ns); // *poff*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is a work around to compile the code without an error by bypassing the access rules of `protected` members. Before we start keep this in mind:
"*In `class X` methods, we can access all its members (`private`, `protected`, `public`), irrespective of the member belongs to `this` object or other object of `class X`.*"

Consider your function again:

```
void Acc(base& b)
{
  x = 5;  // ok, because `x` is a protected member to `this` object
  b.x = 5;  // error, because `b` isn't part of `this` object
}
```

Let's write the above code in little obfuscated way:

```
void Acc(base& b)
{
  this->(base::x) = 5;  // ok, because `x` is a protected member to `this` object
  b.(base::x) = 5;  // error, because `b` isn't part of `this` object
}
```

And still add one more level:

```
void Acc(base& b)
{
  this->*(&der::x) = 5;  // ok, because `x` is a protected member to `this` object
  b.*(&base::x) = 5;  // error, because `b` isn't part of `this` object
}
```

Now if you replace the 2nd statement by writing below statement:

```
b.*(&der::x) = 5;
```

It [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/gLxRad)!
In reality, it's equivalent to `b.x`, but it bypasses the compiler rule which prevents us from writing `b.x = 5;`.

But such kind of statement may often result in **undefined behavior**. Because, imagine what happens if the `b` is passed as a reference of `some_other_derived_class_of_base`! The best bet is to introduce access methods for `x` in `class base`

```
void base::set_x (int v) { x = v; }
```